# Canvas URL related error

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am getting a Canvas URL error like shown below which I am not clear about. I am not clear as to where it is coming from.. I put a debug before and after FB.init() and both are printed. My app is configured under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" as "Website with Facebook Login" only and so I have no canvas URL specified anywhere (there is no option to do so). The only thing I have is "App domains" and "Site URL" and both of these I have set to my website URL (www.blah-blah.com). 
My code is below after the error, but I dont know where the error below is coming from. Any thoughts?

Error:
"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
  console.log("Hello");
  FB.init(
  {
    appId      : 'XXXX', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//www.XXXX.com/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
  console.log("Hello2");
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
  {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
      console.log('Connected case… ');
      testAPI();
    } 
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
      FB.login();
      console.log('Not authorized case… ');
    } 
    else 
    {
      FB.login();
      console.log('else case… ');
    }
  });
};
// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id)
{ 
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) 
  {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s); 
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
} (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function doLogout() 
{
  FB.logout(function(response) 
  {
    //console.log(response);
    alert("Bye bye...");
  });
} 

function testAPI() 
{
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) 
  {
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. Somehow adding "http" to one of the URLs in the FB app settings fixed my problems magically. Sigh.